# Generating Large Prime Numbers with Py Crypto

Tags: python, random, primes, pycrypto

I'm trying to generate a large prime number (2048 bits) using the crypto library in python in order to implement RSA.  However, I do not really understand the syntax of the `getPrime()` function.  I currently have:

```
from Crypto.Util import number

n_length = 2048

primeNum = number.getPrime(n_length, randFunc)
```

I don't understand what the `randFunc` is supposed to be in the `getPrime` function.

Comment: This is a question about python; perhaps stack-exchange would be a better place?

Comment: I think the question is off-topic because software related. The randFunc is a function that outputs random bytes.
From the API docs (https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Util.number-module.html#getPrime): 
getPrime(N, randfunc=None)
getPrime(N:int, randfunc:callable):long Return a random N-bit prime number.
If randfunc is omitted, then Random.new().read is used.

Comment: You might also want to try implementing your own large prime number function. The Fermat primality test is very simple to implement.

Comment: Does that library deliver provable primes or, as is commonly the case with software for large prime number generations, only statistically highly probable primes based on e.g. the Miller-Rabin test? In the 2nd case you may consider preferring to use provable primes instead. I have a Python code implementing Maurer's algorithm of generation of provable primes, with fairly comparable efficiency to employment of Miller-Rabin. See http://s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7234475/1/

Comment: One way to do this is to use RSA library. You can call, `from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA`. Then you create the object, `keyA = RSA.generate(2048)`. Finally, you use  `keyA.p;keyA.q`.

Comment: [typo for the previous comment] since you want 2048 prime number, you have to write  `keyA = RSA.generate(4096)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`n_length` is the "size" of the prime number. It will return a number around 2^n_length. `randFunc` is a callable function that accepts a single argument N and then returns a string of N random bytes. (`os.urandom` is an example of this). In most cases, `randFunc` can (and should) be omitted, since the default is PyCrypto's own random number generator.

Comment: I tried to omit the randFunc part of it, but I get an error saying that the function takes exactly 2 arguments, when only 1 is given.  This is when I try this line: primeNum = number.getPrime(n_length)

Comment: `>>> number.getPrime(16) # 33037L` Do you have a recent version of python and pycrypto? If you're still having issues, try this. `import os; number.getPrime(nbits, os.urandom)`

Comment: yeah. I realized that my pypcrypto was not up-to-date, so I needed to add the os.urandom.  thanks!